# Integral Representation of Gamma & Zeta Functions Inside the Critical Strip

Tags: calculus, gamma-function, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, analytic-continuation

> How to show the validity of the following integral inside the critical strip:
>
> $$ \Gamma(s)\zeta(s)-\Gamma(s-1) = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-2}\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{e^x}\right)\,dx \qquad\colon\space Re\{s\}\gt0 \tag{1} $$

---

By definition:
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(s) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x}\,dx \space\colon\space Re\{s\}\gt0 \space\Rightarrow\space \Gamma(s-1) = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-2}\left(\frac{1}{e^x}\right)\,dx \space\colon\space Re\{s\}\gt1 \\[4mm]
\Gamma(s)\zeta(s) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-2}\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right)\,dx \quad\colon\space Re\{s\}\gt1
\end{align}
$$
Thus:
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)-\Gamma(s-1) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-2}\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{e^x}\right)\,dx \qquad\colon\space Re\{s\}\gt1 \\[4mm]
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-2}\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\color{red}{-1}-\frac{1}{e^x}\color{red}{+1}\right)\,dx \\[4mm]
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-2}\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}-1\right)\,dx - \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-2}\left(\frac{1}{e^x}-1\right)\,dx \space\colon\space \color{red}{Re\{s\}\gt0}
\end{align}
$$
And, if I am not mistaken, this would imply:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \Gamma(s)\zeta(s) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx \quad\colon\space 0\lt Re\{s\}\le1 \tag{2} \\[4mm]
> \Gamma(s) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{e^x}-1\right)\,dx \space\quad\colon\space -1\lt Re\{s\}\le0 \tag{3}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   Is this correct? How can I show these results in another way? Appreciating.

Comment: anything unclear ?

Comment: @user1952009: Many thank for the answer. May I seek your patient, let us see other opinions/answers/votes.

Comment: What do you want more ? If you are not sure of what is happening here, you need to study a complex analysis and a Fourier/Laplace transform course. The first thing is to see why $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ is analytic at $z= 0$

Comment: @user1952009: Thanks for been always interested in my posts, you definitely deserve a bounty for your skills. Regarding this question, appreciating if you could respond to my comment below, I think the answer is still uncompleted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes (1),(2),(3) are correct. A way to show (2) is with the Taylor expansion $\frac{x}{e^x-1}=1+\mathcal{O}(x)$ as $x \to 0$ so that $$\Gamma(s)\zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s-1} = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-2}\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}-1_{x < 1}\right)dx$$ (which is obvious for $Re(s)> 1$) converges and is analytic for $Re(s) > 0$.

Then, use $$\frac{1}{s} = \begin{cases} \ \int_0^1 x^{s-1}dx \ \ \text{ for } Re(s) > 0 \\ \ -\int_1^\infty x^{s-1}dx \text{ for } Re(s) < 0 \end{cases}$$ this is why the [domain of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Region_of_convergence) is so important when talking of a Laplace/Mellin transform.

Note the inverse Laplace/Mellin transforms $$\frac{1}{e^x-1} = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} \zeta(s) \Gamma(s) x^{-s}dx, \quad \sigma > 1$$ $$ \quad \frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} \zeta(s) \Gamma(s) x^{-s}dx, \quad \sigma \in (0,1)$$
the convergence being ensured by $\zeta(s) = \mathcal{O}(s)$ as $ Im(s) \to \infty$ while $\Gamma(s)$ decreases faster than any negative power of $s$ as $Im(s) \to \infty$, since $\Gamma(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-e^{-u}}e^{-su}du$ is the Laplace/Fourier transform of a [Schwartz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) for $Re(s) > 0$.

And see [Riemann's proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242907/xi-function-on-critical-strip-mellin-transform/242959#242959) of the functional equation, starting from $E(s)  = \pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x}dx$ and using that $\theta(x) = 1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x}$ is [modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form), that is $\theta(1/x) = x \theta(x)$ revealing that $E(s) = E(1-s)$.

Comment: I meant $\theta(1/x) = \sqrt{x}\theta(x)$ so it is modular but with a non-integral weight

Comment: Up to my knowledge, analytic continuation of $\,\zeta\,$ by Integral $(2)$ is known {i.e. books of  E.C. Titchmarsh & Aleksandar Ivic}, while analytic continuation of $\,\Gamma\,$ by Integral $(3)$ is not. Would you please explain Integral $(3)$, at least in similar way of explaining Integral $(2)$. Thanks.

Comment: @HazemOrabi For $(2)$ or $(3)$ it really works the same way. $e^{-x}-1_{x < 1} = \mathcal{O}(x)$ as $x \to 0$ so that $\Gamma(s) - \frac{1}{s} = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} (e^{-x}-1_{x < 1})dx$ for $Re(s) > 0$ stays convergent and analytic for $Re(s) > -1$. Then add $\frac{1}{s} = -\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} 1_{x > 1} dx \ (Re(s) < 0)$ for obtaining $(2)$

Comment: Meanwhile, **for the benefit of public readers**, whenever you have time, kindly review/revise your answer to include everything about the question on a bit more comprehensive/clear way. Do so, and I shall have no excuse not to accept it!